# Job ID contains filter in Google Cloud ML API

Tags: google-cloud-ml

I'm referring to the Google Cloud ML Engine API, in particular this method:
https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/ml/m/ml/v1/ml.projects.jobs.list

What is the filter syntax one should us for the 'Job ID Contains' filter as per the UI?

[image]

I'm able to use the State filter as:

```
state:"RUNNING" OR state:"FAILED"
```

but none of the following work:

```
job id contains:"mytext"
'job id contains':"mytext"
'JobIDContains':"mytext"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out it is super simple:

```
jobId:mytext
```

Here are some details on filters: 
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/filters where the above is an example of

> key : simple-pattern